# Django_Password_Expiry_not_working

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

**setting.py**

`PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT = 120`

**views.py**

```
    def login(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            uname = request.POST['uname']
            pwd = request.POST['pwd']
            user = authenticate(username=uname, password=pwd)
            if user is not None:
                if user.is_active:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('home')
        else:
            return render(request, 'login.html')
```

**models.py**

```
    class RegisterUser(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        mobile = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        password_expiry = models.TimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        def __str__(self):
            return self.user.username
```

Does anyone know how to set password expiry in django for 2 minutes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in the Django docs for [PASSWORD_RESET_TIMEOUT](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#password-reset-timeout), this timeout is used by the `PasswordResetConfirmView`.

You can use it e.g. directly via the URL patterns (for example with a custom template as well):

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import PasswordResetConfirmView

urlpatterns = [
    path(
        "reset/<uidb64>/<token>/",
        PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(
            template_name="my_custom_reset_template.html"
        ),
    ),
    ...
```

Comment: [Marco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4151233/marco) thanks